# LexikFormFilterBundle select multiple dates

Tags: php, bundle, symfony

I would like to have a filter for several dates, for example a whole week of a whole month. I have tried severals ways to do it but noone succeded. I am not very used to this bundle and I don't find the way to select correctly my dates.

```
    $builder->add('receptionCommande', DateFilterType::class, array(
        'widget'    => 'text',
        'required'  => false,
        'format'    => 'dd / MM / yyyy',
        'input'     => 'string',
        'attr'      => array('day' => '%'),
        'days'      => array('data' => '%')
    ));
```

I was trying here to put a joker value on days.

```
    $builder->add('receptionCommande', TextFilterType::class, array(
        'data_class'     => 'year'
    ));
```

Here I wanted to select only the year of the date, but this didn't succeded. I'm struggeling with this for hours. Does anyone knows how to do, or even have a hint to guide me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the filter_`date_range` Type that help you select a date interval.

As example:

```
    $builder->add('receptionCommande', DateRangeFilterType::class, array(
     'left_date_options' => array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker'),
        'widget'    => 'single_text',
        ),
     'right_date_options' => array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker'),
        'widget'    => 'single_text',
        ),
     'label' => 'A Range of date',
     ));
```

Hope this help

Comment: This works well, thanks. I have tried without `'class' => 'datepicker'` but I was limited on years. Now I have to find a way to makes this works correctly on IE8 (somes of my users are still on Windows XP and IE is required for another tool). I just need something fast, like the native date on Chrome. I tried `'data-format': 'dd/MM/yyyy'` without success sadly.

Comment: Hi @Tartare2240 You are welcome!  if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Consider to upvote my answer also.